# PostgreSQL calculate threshold query

Tags: sql, postgresql, math, window-functions, threshold

i have postgresql db with a table t1 and i want to calculate a threshold.
the threshold should be for example car 1 uses more fuel than 75 % of all cars, car2 uses more fuel than 50% of all cars, .... 
mathematically i understand what i want to do, but i dont know how to build the query

```
id | name | value | threshold
________________________

1  | car1 |  30   |  ...%
2  | car2 |  15   |  ..%
3  | car3 |   7   |
4  | car4 |   5   |
```

here is a sql fiddle
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/1e914/1

```
UPDATE t1
SET threshold = 
    select count(value)
     from t1
```

where (value > [over each row])
  and followed by *100/the overall count()

sorry for that bad try but i am kind of lost. also tried some aggregate functions.

Comment: Have a look at `100 * PERCENT_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY value)` or `100 * CUME_DIST() OVER (ORDER BY value)`

Comment: @dnoeth Both of these do not work because the solution is relative to the most fuel-efficient car and not calculated over the entire population.

Comment: @Patrick: If those functions don't work then your answer is not correct, too. Both are just slight variations of your `RANK/COUNT` :-)

Comment: @dnoeth Not true. I am using `(rank() - 1) / count()` which gives exactly the results in this question. The `- 1` may be slight but it is the reason why you can't use the built-in functions.

Comment: @Patrick: Ok, based on the expected result both are not correct, but this was just a description based on four rows :-) That's why I wrote he should see if those functions fit his needs. `PERCENT_RANK` is based on `(RANK-1)/(COUNT-1)`, i.e. the number of rows with a value **less than** the current value and `CUME_DIST` is based on **less than or equal**.

Comment: at the end it is the same like percentile or am i wrong?  ntile(100) OVER(ORDER BY value)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can solve this quite elegantly with a [window function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html):

```
UPDATE t1
SET threshold = sub.thr
FROM (
  SELECT id, 100. * (rank() OVER (ORDER BY value) - 1) / count(*) OVER () AS thr
  FROM t1) sub
WHERE t1.id = sub.id;
```

The `rank()` function gives the rank (starting from 1) in an ordered set, in this case over the column `value`, which is then divided by the total number of rows in the set. Note that `count(*) OVER ()` calculates the total number of rows in th *partition* but it does not aggregate the rows like a regular `count(*)` would.

Comment: thank you all for the help. at the sqlfiddle link above you can see the differences between rank(),percent_rank(),cume_dist(). i think i was looking for percent_rank. i changed the order, now i can say 33% of the cars use more fuel than car2. (by the way my real table is not about cars). one thing to add, window-functions dont work with UPDATE

Comment: You can wrap the window functions in a sub-select and then it should work. See updated answer. Note that the use of `percent_rank()` gives a result that is different from what you state in your question. There the percentage is relative to the most fuel efficient car, while the function calculates against all rows. `(rank() - 1) / count(*)` gives exactly the result you were asking for.

Comment: true, the (rank() ... is the right function, that works for my question. thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH    q AS
        (
        SELECT  *,
                (RANK() OVER (ORDER BY value) - 1) * 100. / COUNT(*) OVER () nt
        FROM mytable
        )
UPDATE  mytable
SET     threshold = nt
FROM    q
WHERE   mytable.id = q.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to calculate percentage of using fuel?

```
UPDATE t1 
SET threshold = 
    (select value * 100 / t2.sumValue
    from (select sum(value) sumValue from t1) t2
    )
```

Or if you want to calculate specific threshold, may you show your expected result?